# Is it possibile that emails are blocked by gmail while sending several emails through cron job?

Tags: python, cron, gmail-api

I have a question concerning the behavior of my code. The code below does the following: 
- get credentials for gmail API
- tries to send a message
- in the mean time, a cron job is working

I noticed that they work fine together. Now, the first message is sent and received well. But then the second and all other mails are sent but never reach the receipient. First email is received in the inbox. I checked the Spam folder but there's nothing there. I checked the Sent folder of the sender and the mails are all sent. 
I am new to both elements and I can't figure out what's going on.

Here's my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
import atexit
import time

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from flask import Flask

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger

import base64
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes

app = Flask(__name__)

try:
   import argparse
   flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
   flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/gmail-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'http://mail.google.com'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
"""Gets valid user credentials from storage.

If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

Returns:
    Credentials, the obtained credential.
"""
current_dir = os.getcwd()
credential_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, '.credentials')
if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
    os.makedirs(credential_dir)
credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                               'gmail-python-quickstart.json')

store = Storage(credential_path)
credentials = store.get()
if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
    flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
    if flags:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
    else:       # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
        credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
    print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
return credentials


def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}


def send_message(service, user_id, message):
  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
              .execute())
    print ('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
    return message
  except:
    print ('An error occurred')


@app.route("/home")
def main():
"""Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.

Creates a Gmail API service object and outputs a list of label names
of the user's Gmail account.
"""
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

message = create_message('foo@foo.com', 'foo@foo.com', 'Test', 'Ciao')
send_message(service, 'me', message)
print(time.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p"))


scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()
scheduler.add_job(
    func=main,
    trigger=IntervalTrigger(seconds=20),
    id='printing_job',
    name='Print date and time every five seconds',
    replace_existing=True)
# Shut down the scheduler when exiting the app
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I would like to know if I am missing something.

I tried sending both receipient and sender email addresses but nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you checked in spams box? and you received first mail in the inbox?

Comment: @kirankumarkotari first email was received in the inbox as a normal mail. I checked spams but there's nothing there.

Comment: I changed the IntervalTrigger into 300seconds and it works fine. It seems like 20 seconds are too short.

Comment: when the interval shortened it doesn't creates a digital signature to it that might be the case. Few times it may land in spam box or missing in mailer box assuming this is an attack due to lack of DS.